# How to measure the response time in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tokenize, stop-words

I am using Tokenizer and StopWordsRemover in spark-shell (with Scala) following these links:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tokenizer

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stopwordsremover

I want to add a command that calculates the response time for each algorithm.
How can I do this and at any level ? Any idea please.